# ReactJS, react-bootstrap, Modal Box: "Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal, state, onload, react-bootstrap

I'm learning ReactJS, and I'm building my first component using react-bootstrap.

I integrated without problems the modal, but I'm trying to check if browser is not Internet Explorer to launch a modal box, and get this error: "Modal Box: "Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop." Probably is a very basic thing related to updating the state properly, maybe you can help me, this is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

function ModalStd () {

    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
    const customClass = "modal-std";

    function isIE() {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        var is_ie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1 || ua.indexOf("Trident/") > -1;
        return is_ie;
    }

    if (!isIE()) {
        handleShow(); // here is the issue I think
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
                Launch modal
            </Button>

            <Modal backdropClassName={customClass}
                   dialogClassName={customClass}
                   show={show} onHide={handleClose}
                   animation={false}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body></Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
                        Close
                    </Button>
                    {/*<Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
                        Save Changes
                    </Button>*/}
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </>
    );
}

export default ModalStd;
``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move handleShow to `componentDidMount` like:

```js
useEffect(() => {
   if (!isIE()) {
        handleShow(); // here is the issue I think
    }
}, []) // it is equivalent to componentDidMount in React classes
```

And move `isIE` outside of the component. Because any statements inside a hook will be called everytime the component is updated(due to state or props change).

Comment: Thanks! @bravemaster. Not sure why "componentDidMount() {
  }" is marked in red by Phpstorm, when I intruduce it in the script, so I didn't use it, but I introduce the useEffect you worte, and take out the isIE() function.

Comment: componentDidMount is for React classes. You're using React hooks. My approach(useEffect with an empty array) is an equivalent for componentDidMount.

Comment: Consider accept/approve my answer if it was helpful.

Comment: yes of course, I will accept your answer!. There is another thing that is getting me crazy... :-( ,  I will have to write another post.